# Convert WallClock Time from one timezone to another timezone

Tags: java, simpledateformat, date

I want to convert wall clock time time from one TZ to another **without doing OFFSET math myself.**

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss z");
    String d = sdf.format(new Date());
    System.out.println(d);
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
    String d1 = sdf.format(new Date());
    System.out.println(d1);
```

Output:

```
2018.07.09 13:43:30 PDT
2018.07.09 16:43:30 EDT
```

Desired Output

```
2018.07.09 13:43:30 PDT
2018.07.09 13:43:30 EDT
```

How can I get the desired output?

Comment: Any reason why you can't use the newer date/time API?

Comment: @MadProgrammer As of now, we use Java 7. We have not upgraded our infra to java 8 if you are referring to ZonedDateTime.

Comment: So your desired output is supposed to be two _different_ moments in time?  Slightly tricky in Java 7 (without Joda time or the new Java 8 date/time API).

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Available for Java (6 and) 7 in [the ThreeTen Backport library](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### java.time and ThreeTen Backport

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss z", Locale.US);

    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"));
    String d = zdt.format(formatter);
    System.out.println(d);

    zdt = zdt.withZoneSameLocal(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
    String d1 = zdt.format(formatter);
    System.out.println(d1);
```

Output when I ran the code just now:

```
2018.07.10 04:30:20 PDT
2018.07.10 04:30:20 EDT
```

The `ZonedDateTime` class that you mentioned in a comment has your desired conversion built in, in its `withZoneSameLocal` method. This returns the same wall clock time in the specified time zone.

> As of now, we use Java 7. We have not upgraded our infra to java 8…

No big problem. `java.time` and its `ZonedDateTime` work nicely on Java 7. They just require at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26, I’m told) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time`to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Comment: But there is no toInstant method for Date in java 7. How do I connvert a java.util.Date to ZoneDateTime

Comment: Hi, when you use the ThreeTen Backport library mentioned, conversion from `Date` to `Instant` is done with `DateTimeUtils.toInstant(yourJavaUtilDate)`.